# Firefox ignoring default search engine preferences

Tags: javascript, firefox

In the `user.js` file for my profile, I have the following lines:

```
user_pref("browser.search.defaultenginename", "Google");
user_pref("browser.search.defaultenginename.US", "data:text/plain,browser.search.defaultenginename.US=Google");
user_pref("browser.search.selectedEngine", "Google");
```

Checking in `about:config`, I can see that the preferences have been updated, but searching in the URL bar produces a Yahoo search page.

Firefox seems to just ignore the preferences and nothing but manually setting the search engine to Google in the UI actually does anything.

Comment: Not really a programming question is it? but, what do you is in `about:preferences#search`

Comment: @JaromandaX Do you have any suggestions of where else I can post this question? That's what the last line of the post is about. Using the dropdown on `about:preferences#search` works perfectly fine, but nothing I do in the `user.js` file does anything.

Comment: so, changes in `user.js` are reflected in `about:preferences#search`? if not, it may be that the preferences you are changing are "legacy"

Comment: @JaromandaX No the changes do not show up in `about:preferences#search`. there aren't any other settings in `about:config` about the default engine other than the ones I'm changing.

Comment: I guess firefox no longer uses those preferences for search engine management then

Comment: @JaromandaX I hope not

Comment: Why? The ui is perfectly cromulent

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes but as the question indicates, I would like this to be able to be accomplished in code

Comment: In code? Surely not on a web page

Comment: @JaromandaX No the `user.js` file

Answer (score 0):

From this article, it looks like Mozilla have removed the ability to set/change/hijack the search engine via `user.js`:

http://www.ghacks.net/2014/08/07/firefox-34-to-introduce-better-search-hijacking-protection/

> Mozilla plans to improve user protection against search hijacking in
> several ways in the near future. One effort will be integrated into
> Firefox 34.
>
> The preference browser.search.selectedEngine, which is currently being
> used to determine the default search engine in Firefox, will be
> removed as a consequence.

The article also mentions the following, but it looks obsolete as I can't see any `search-metadata.json` file:

> The value of the preference will be saved in the file
> search-metadata.json instead which is stored in the user's profile
> directory. Since it would be relatively easy to replace that file, a
> hash is added to it as well which is generated from the profile
> directory name.

I also found this bug but haven't done a deep dive to figure out if there's another way to set the search engine:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1405670